# Maven: Use <pluginManagement> as <plugins>

Tags: maven

Instead of having to redundantly specify all plugins and their versions twice, is there a way to specify in a pom.xml that the <plugins> tag should consist of all the plugins listed in <pluginManagement>, when I don't fall into any of the legitimate use cases for divergence between the two?

Comment: Can you please more in detail explain what your question is? Apart from that pluginManagement is intended to define the versions and default configuration (if you need to change them). Repeating in plugins sounds wrong and for what purpose are you doing this?

Answer (score 1):

A common approach is to define all plugins in a parent pom and inherit them. Then you can alter the plugin versions and configurations you need to change, and keep all the "normal" stuff.

PluginManagement can only be used for setting versions and configurations, not for actually activating the plugins.